# Sum rows into field

Tags: database, ms-access, datatable, sum

I have an access database with two tables.
Table 1: InCome
ID - Name - Quantity

Table 2: OutCome
ID - income_id - Quantity

And a relationship between ID in T1 and income_id in T2.

How to insert a calculated  field in T1 to show the sum of outcoming quantity for each row in T1 from T2.

I want to calculate the remaining quantity for each record in T1.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot have calculation in table that summarizes another table. This is what queries are for. Aggregate Table2 data by Income_ID in a query and join that query to Table1. Can nest aggregate query to create a single SQL statement. Consider:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Quantity-TotOut AS Bal FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT Income_ID, Sum(Quantity) AS TotOut FROM Table2 GROUP BY Income_ID) AS Out 
ON Table1.Income_ID = Out.Income_ID;
```

Alternatively, build a report and do aggregate calcs in design. A report allows display of raw data as well as summary data.

Comment: I have try this way, but with records in table 1 wich doesn't have any out quantity in table 2 then it doesn't appear in the query, therefore i can't calculate the remaining quantity for it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have shown RIGHT or LEFT JOIN in query. Try LEFT.